# Возможна ли работа python с журналом буфера обмена Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, clipboard

Возможна ли работа python с журналом буфера обмена (вызывается клавишами `win+v`)?
У windows вроде как есть для этого api: [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard?view=winrt-22621).
Может даже возможна реализация через ctypes или pywin32?

Comment: Если не принципиально winapi, можно использовать [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/). Но работает только с текстом. Хотя, там не совсем видимо то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Если есть соответствующие функции win api, то в принципе ничего не мешает обратиться к ним через ctypes или pywin32. Так что короткий ответ - да.

Comment: Только по ссылке, которую вы привели, это не WinAPI, а класс C#. Вам нужна эта ссылка: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Comment: Insolor, спасибо вам. Я вскором времени постараюсь вам дать ответ. Думаю это то что мне нужно.